# Does MongoDB supports TLS1.2 version or above?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, tls1.2, mongo-java, mongo-shell

This is regarding security part of MongoDB.

I saw the documentation of MongoDB and found that it supports TLS 1.0 & 1.1.

May I know does MongoDB supports TLS 1.2 version or above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does, for a while now. It's mentioned [here](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-security-part-1-design-and-configuration) in a MongoDB blog post on May 21, 2014:

> In order to protect the network traffic, SSL/TLS should be enabled
>   between clients and the server and in between servers. MongoDB
>   supports TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2, all SSL versions are disabled. Enabling
>   TLS is well described in the [security documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-network/).

See [Source on GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/util/net/ssl_manager.cpp).

Comment: Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0):

**Looks like 1.3 is also supported:**

```
void recordTLSVersion(TLSVersion version, const HostAndPort& hostForLogging) {
StringData versionString;
auto& counts = mongo::TLSVersionCounts::get(getGlobalServiceContext());
switch (version) {
    case TLSVersion::kTLS10:
        counts.tls10.addAndFetch(1);
        if (std::find(sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cbegin(),
                      sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend(),
                      SSLParams::Protocols::TLS1_0) != sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend()) {
            versionString = "1.0"_sd;
        }
        break;
    case TLSVersion::kTLS11:
        counts.tls11.addAndFetch(1);
        if (std::find(sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cbegin(),
                      sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend(),
                      SSLParams::Protocols::TLS1_1) != sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend()) {
            versionString = "1.1"_sd;
        }
        break;
    case TLSVersion::kTLS12:
        counts.tls12.addAndFetch(1);
        if (std::find(sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cbegin(),
                      sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend(),
                      SSLParams::Protocols::TLS1_2) != sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend()) {
            versionString = "1.2"_sd;
        }
        break;
    case TLSVersion::kTLS13:
        counts.tls13.addAndFetch(1);
        if (std::find(sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cbegin(),
                      sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend(),
                      SSLParams::Protocols::TLS1_3) != sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.cend()) {
            versionString = "1.3"_sd;
        }
        break;
    default:
        counts.tlsUnknown.addAndFetch(1);
        if (!sslGlobalParams.tlsLogVersions.empty()) {
            versionString = "unknown"_sd;
        }
        break;
}
```